# Where to place export apk in Samsung galaxy s5

Tags: android, apk, osx-mavericks, samsung-mobile, android-install-apk

I am trying to test my export (proguard) apk on Samsung galaxy s5. But it’s not clear to me in which directory to put it. If you ever use a mac with android device, you know that for many phones, when you plug them to your computer,  the `Android File Transfer` directory comes with a subdirectory clearly labeled `APK`. So normally I drop my apk there, and then do the rest on the device itself. But for samsung s5, there is no such folder. So in what subdirectory do I place the file? Has anyone done this successfully? My phone is already configured for development. I develop the app using it and eclipse. Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I usually do it is to put it on a test server, then download it and open it. ie. http://www.myserver.com/my.apk and then open it. The other way is to connect your phone via adb and do an `adb push yourapk.apk`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `adb install package_name.apk`